# Are ndarray assingments to different indexes threadsafe?

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, thread-safety, numpy-ndarray

I have 1000 images of size (800,800,3) and I need to load them with multiple threads into a numpy array of size (1000,800,800,3). Do I need to lock between assingments, even if two different threads won’t ever assign anything to or access the same index?